# How can I spin the image along Z axis in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am using Transform widget in my flutter code to rotate the screen

```
Offset _offset = Offset.zero;

return new Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
               ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
               ..rotateX(0.01 * _offset.dy)
               ..rotateY(-0.01 * _offset.dx)
               ..rotateZ(- 0.01 * _offset.),
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("The 3D Matrix"),
          ),
          body: GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (details) => setState(() => _offset += details.delta),
              onDoubleTap: () => setState(() => _offset = Offset.zero),
              child: Content())
        ),);
```

Now what I want is to spin the widget along z-axis with certain velocity and slow down it's speed to zero after few seconds.

May be I need to use the Animation Controller. How can we achieve this state?

Right now I achieved this much: [image: Look Here]

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an `AnimationController` to your page widget. Then wrap your `Transform` into a `AnimatedBuilder`

And when you need to start the animation, call `animationController.forward()`.

```
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return new Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
            ..rotateZ(animationController.value * 45.0),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("The 3D Matrix"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => animationController.forward(),
            child: new Text("Start anim"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just want to add one more feature of spinning in my Gesture widget as onTap or onLongPressed and keeping all the feature same. You just Showed my spinning feature.

Comment: What else do you need ?

Comment: I want two of my features of GestureDetector same and some how add one more attribute of onTap() => which start the spinning of the activity and then slowly return to its original state.

Comment: Can you explain what setEntry does?